# How can I filter specific user on Views list?

Tags: 7, users, views

Using Views 3.

I have User view and here, list all user by post count. It's working. But I want, ignore admin user post count in this view. How can I filter my views to not show admin in the view list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add a filter criteria of type `User: Roles`,
2. Select the operator `Is none of:`
3. Select `Administrator` from the listbox.
4. Save the settings

This will block the display of all the users with role as administrators. If you only want to limit a certain user you can select the filter criteria of `User: Name`, or `User: The User ID`, whatever suits you.

Answer (score 3):

1. Add a filter "user id: uid"
2. In the filter settings, select "not equal to" and put in 1 as value. Similarly if you want any other user excluded, please add the corresponding uids.

I am not having a set up with me right now, so the labels might not be exact, but please keep looking for similar options as i had mentioned in the filter settings.

Answer (score 2):

Create a filter in the in views as following:

1. Select the filter: `User: The user ID`
2. Select the operator: `Is not equal to`
3. Enter the Value: `1` ("Enter the user of the admin i.e 1, or the user id of any user whose post you want to hide")
4. Save the view

[image]

**Note:** If you want to hide the post of particular role instead of particular user than instead of selecting the filter as `User: The user ID` select the filter as `User: Roles` and select operator as `Is none of` and than select the all the roles of user whose post you want to hide.